# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appium' (yes I have appium, adk, and appium-python-client)

Tags: python, android, appium

I'm trying to get started up using appium, and have gotten this error when I try to import appium in python:

```
C:\Users\Sams PC>python
Python 3.8.4 (tags/v3.8.4:dfa645a, Jul 13 2020, 16:46:45) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import appium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'appium'
```

To cover what I have:

Appium:

```
C:\Users\Sams PC>appium
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.17.1
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

Appium-python-client

```
C:\Users\Sams PC>pip install appium-python-client
Requirement already satisfied: appium-python-client in c:\users\sams pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: selenium<4,>=3.14.1 in c:\users\sams pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from appium-python-client) (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\sams pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from selenium<4,>=3.14.1->appium-python-client) (1.25.7)

C:\Users\Sams PC>
```

I have installed and setup Android Studio:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C08F-2C8E

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio

07/15/2020  06:26 PM    <DIR>          .
07/15/2020  06:26 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/15/2020  06:26 PM             1,181 Android Studio.lnk
               1 File(s)          1,181 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  30,455,201,792 bytes free
```

I've looked at all the other similar questions, but I don't quite understand what I'm missing since I've downloaded everything required from the looks of it.

Comment: can you check if `pip` and `python` are from same path.

Answer (score 1):

You pip is pointing towards Python 3.7 and your Python is on 3.8.
Change pip path pointing to 3.7 to 3.8 and then again do `pip install Appium-Python-Client`